# ipad UIImagePickerController problem?

Tags: iphone, ipad

My app is an iphone app not an universal app.I am implementing uiimagepickercontroller it's     working fine in iphone .But our client test my app on ipad the app will crash.I find out the   issue 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'
I am checking device by

> **NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;**

(This code work in universal app)
implementing UIPopoverController for iPad only. But deviceType always displays 'iPhone' even if i change to iPad simulator.Is it possible to solve this issue in iphone Build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did iPad for separately to solve this issue.because i can't get a device type iPad in iPhone app.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` macro to check for device.

```
if (UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM())
{
    // your code
}
```

`UIDevice` is not the right choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `userInterfaceIdiom` property of [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

Answer (score -1):

Like Erica Sadun said you can access device string with:

```
- (NSString *) getSysInfoByName:(char *)typeSpecifier
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *answer = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, answer, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *results = [NSString stringWithCString:answer encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(answer);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: There's available hi-level classes and functions that allows to determine device type application is running on. No need to rely on low-level API, this may cause incompatibility and other troubles in future.

Comment: You're right about there is no need to rely on low-level api to determine the device type, but i could not find resources to determine the hardware model name.